Trigonometry Question: $\sqrt{13-12\cos x}+ \sqrt{7-4\sqrt3\sin x }=2\sqrt3$
![Sqrt(13-12cosx) + sqrt(7-4sqrt3sinx =2sqrt3][1]
Hi I have started solving the question I have constructed a triangle with base as $3$ and height as $\sqrt3$. Both terms gives a cosine formula then I

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the quite similar AoPS thread Solve trigonometric equation, with the only differences being the $13$ in the first square root being replaced by $15$, and your RHS value of $2\sqrt{3}$ being $4$ instead. I haven't tried working out the details, but I suspect the approach used there could also work with your problem.

Potential hint: $$\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} = c \implies 2(ab + ac + bc) = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$$

Revision 6 removes some work and details of the problem, but MathJax and other details can be edited in afterwards.

In the final configuration you have reached, applying Stewart's Theorem gives
$$3a+9b = (a+b)(4+ab).$$
We know $a+b=2\sqrt3$, hence we obtain
$$3a+9b = 2\sqrt3(4+ab)$$
or equivalently, using $3a+9b = 6(a+b) - 3(a-b) = 12\sqrt3 - 3(a-b)$,
$$12\sqrt3 - 3(a-b) = 2\sqrt3(4+ab)$$
or
$\begin{equation}
4-2ab = \sqrt3(a-b).
\end{equation}$
Squaring both sides, we get
$\begin{align}
16-16ab+4(ab)^2 &= 3(a^2-2ab+b^2)\\
&= 3(a^2 + 2ab + b^2 - 4ab)\\
&= 3(12-4ab)\\
&= 36 - 12ab
\end{align}$
using which we get the equation $$4(ab)^2 - 4ab + 1 = 21.$$ Thus, $$2ab = 1 \pm \sqrt{21}.$$ Since $ab>0$, we must have $$2ab = 1 + \sqrt{21}.$$
We knew $4-2ab = \sqrt3(a-b)$, which gives us $$b-a = \sqrt{7}-\sqrt{3}.$$ Using this equation along with $b+a = 2\sqrt3$, solving the linear system gives us the exact values of $a$ and $b$ to be
$\begin{align}
a &= \dfrac{3\sqrt3 - \sqrt7}{2},\\
b &= \dfrac{\sqrt3 + \sqrt7}{2}.
\end{align}$
Finally, Law of Cosines in $\Delta DBC$ gives us
$\begin{align}
x &= \arccos \left( \dfrac{3+\sqrt{21}}{8} \right)\\
&\approx 18.59^\circ.
\end{align}$
